# Dynamics CRM Plug-in with PATCH request

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm writing a plug-in to send a PATCH request to the REST API whenever a new opportunity is created. But I keep getting the same error "400 Bad Request". However, I tested the URL in POSTMAN and it works fine. This is my code (the plug-in will call this method):

```
private async void MakeRequest(string requestUrl, ITracingService tracingService)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(requestUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                .Accept
                .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), "relativeAddress");

            request.Content = new StringContent("{\"op\":\"replace\",\"path\":\"prescriptive-actions/status\",\"value\":\"Completed\",\"from\":\"New\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            tracingService.Trace("requestUrl {0}", requestUrl);

            var task = client.SendAsync(request)
                .ContinueWith(responseTask =>
                {
                    tracingService.Trace("responseTask {0}", responseTask.Result);
                });

            task.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tracingService.Trace("PROSPluginNotifyPAO Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 1**
This is for CRM Online 2015. And below is the stack trace

```
requestUrl http://prospaodev.azure-api.net/hpho/prescriptive-actions/678391
    responseTask StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
    {
    Date: Tue, 06 Oct 2015 23:04:11 GMT
    Content-Length: 0
    }
```

Comment: Is your CRM on-premise or online?

Comment: Is your url targeting an IP address? Can you share a stack trace?

Comment: @user3305040 Is "relativeAddress" really the HttpRequestMessage.RequestUri?